# Puzzle involving arithmetic series - will this game always end

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, puzzle, arithmetic-progressions

I'm playing a game. I get a short sequence of increasing numbers, and I try to "fill in the blanks" using the minimal distance between two consecutive elements.

For example. Suppose I got the sequence $x_1 = 1,4,7,13, 22$. The minimal distance is $d=3$, the initial value is $1$.

I will then output the sequence $y = 1, 4, 7,10,13,16,19,22$

Easy stuff.

**The hard part begins when the numbers don't line up correctly**

Suppose I got the sequence $x_1 = 1, 3, 6,8$. The minimum distance is $d=2$, the initial value is $1$

So I will output $y=1,3,5,6,7,8$.

**But that is an incorrect output since that's not an arithmetic series**. So I will do it again, this time with $x_2 = 1,3,5,6,7,8$. The minimal distance is $d=1$, the initial value is $1$, so I will output $y = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$

My question is - Is the game guaranteed to always end? Will I eventually reach an arithmetic series, on any initial input? or are there inputs that I will get closer and closer to arithmetic without actually reaching it.

Edit: In case it wasn't completely clear, the input sequence we were given may use rational numbers. $1, 3, 6, 6.4$ is a valid input, for instance.

Comment: I do not quite get how we arrive at $1,3,5,6,7,8$. What exactly is the rule for the new sequence ?

Comment: @Peter Start from the first one and generate the arithmetic progression from there?

Comment: You find the minimal distance between two consecutive elements in the old sequence, and you start summing up from the first element of that sequence. We had $1,3,6,8$, the minimal distance is $2$. The initial value is $1$, so our sequence is $1, 1+2, 1+2+2,...$, and then adding the numbers in the old sequence, and sorting it.

Comment: You say that the numbers need not be integers. Are irrational numbers allowed ?

Comment: No, only rationals are allowed.

Comment: May I just raise a point? why not simply try finding arithmatic mean between two numbers and try to proceed? (just an idea)

Comment: Intuitively, I would say that we always end with an arithmetic progression : We get a smaller minimal distance if a new number lands between numbers already present.

Comment: Moreover, I think (but I am not sure) that we can assume that the numbers are integers because if we multiply the original sequence with a positive integer to remove the denominators, the procedure should be equivalent to that from the original sequence. Together with the decreasing minimal distance (in the case we still do not have an arithmetic progression) this should prove that we always arrive at an arithmetic progression. But I do not have a strict argument yet.

Comment: I would agree that definitely $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ is an arithmetic series. But I need a finite number, I need the algorithm to end, not run forever

Comment: I am pretty sure (although I have no proof yet) that we only need finite many steps. If both thoughts I mentioned are valid, it can be proven this way.

Comment: is this an integer sequence?

Comment: @miracle173 Good answer, but could you work out the proof a bit ?

Comment: @Peter What is not clear in the proof?

Comment: You should add arguments (for example that the minimal difference will become smaller unless we already have an arithmetic progression) showing that always an arithmetic progression will appear and a reason why the minimal distance will be the gcd of the original differences. This is intuitively plausible, but requires some strict arguments. Maybe bezout's theorem helps.

Comment: @Peter the argument is "you can add only finitely many additional numbers to your sequence"  I do not use that the minimal differences become smaller. or that the difference will become the gcd.  -- I was not notified by your comment because it does not contain my name prepended by the at-sign.  It makes more sense to diskuss my answer using comments to my anser nd not comments to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the sequence is a sequence strongly monotonic increasing rational numbers.

**Proposition 1:** It will end if it is an integer sequence.

**Proof:** You can add only finitely many additional numbers to the sequence $\left<a_1,\ldots,a_n\right>$ because the numbers must be between $a_1$ and $a_n$.

When the process ends with  the difference $d$ it can be shown that
$$d=\gcd(a_2-a_1,\ldots,a_n-a_{n-1})$$

If it is a rational sequence then you can multiply the sequence members by their smallest common denominator and get an integer sequence.

**Example:**
$$\left< \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{5} \right> \tag{1}$$

The smallest common divisor is  3030. We multiply the sequence by $30$ and get
$$\left<10,15,18 \right>$$. After processing it in the way you described we will end with
$$\left<10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 \right>$$
dividing by 3030 results in
$$\left< \frac{1}{3},  \frac{11}{30}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{13}{30}, \frac{7}{15}, 
\frac{1}{2}, \frac{8}{15}, \frac{17}{30}, \frac{3}{5} \right>$$
This is the same sequence that you will get if your directly process $(1)$.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but gcd only works on integers no?

Comment: @RickJoker The Euclidean algorithm can be generalised to rationals as well :D

Comment: Correct, the gcd of $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ would be $\frac{1}{6}$, for example.

Comment: @RickJoker Please read my  sentence about rational sequences, it shows a simple way how you could process rational sequences.

Comment: Why the gcd of the differences?